# Pull specific folder from heroku into github

Tags: git, heroku, github

I deployed a simple app into Heroku. It's a MEME generator.

When users interact with it through the web, files are created in a "c" folder in the server, but any time I update code on my local machine, push it to github and then to Heroku, the folder, which is empty on my local machine and on github, gets also emptied on the server.

Is there a way to download the contents of that specific folder as a backup before pushing? or Is there a way to set a .gitignore to avoid pushing that "c" folder from github to heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you should operate on Heroku.

On Heroku, dynos are short-lived, and you shouldn't rely on their storage, which is deleted when they are restarted.

Pushing a new release of your code will always restart the dynos, so adding `c` to `.gitignore` won't change a thing.

---

Instead of trying to save to your local disk, you should use an object store for user uploads, such as Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage.